# How to show plist data into UIPickerVIew using Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist, uipickerview

This is the Plist Data Which I want to show in UIPickerView, Basically I want two picker view and two labels 1) UIpickerview will show Occupancy Code 2) UIPickerView will should show Description of Occupancy this two picker are connected to each other, suppose if I select any Occupancy code then in second picker as per that occupancy code value should be change for that code in second UIPickerView 3) After we get two values, we need data on the label the third value should be displayed as per selected in picker 1 or picker 2 4) the last label will also show the related data to the selected value in PickerView 1

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var occupancyTextBox: UITextField!
    
    //MARK: Variables
    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    var pickerViewOccupancy = UIPickerView()
    var occupancy = [""]
    var stateInfo:[(occupancycode: String, ocCode: String)] = [("Gujarat", "India")]
    
    
    
    var arrData = [[String : String]]()
    
    var selectedValue = ""
    var occupancyValue = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  plistData = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: plistsource)
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "firedata", withExtension: "plist")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String : Any]]
        
        
        let allItems = plist
        
        for item in allItems {
            
            let dict: [String: String] = [
                "Occupancy Code": item["Occupancy Code"] as? String ?? "No Occupancy Code",
                "Description of Occupancy": item["Description of Occupancy"] as? String ?? "No Description of Occupancy"
            ]
            
            self.arrData.append(dict)
            // let ocode = item["Occupancy Code"]
            
            print(arrData)
           `Possible to add Plist Data in Array` 
        }
        
        occupancyTextBox.delegate = self
        createPickerView()
        dismissPickerView()
        
       }
      }

        
     extension ViewController {
           func createPickerView() {
           //        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerViewOccupancy.delegate = self
        //        pickerViewOccupancycode.delegate = self
        //        pickerViewEarthquackzone.delegate = self
        
        
        occupancyTextBox.inputView = pickerViewOccupancy
        //        occupancycodeTextBox.inputView = pickerViewOccupancycode
        //        earthquackzoneTextBox.inputView = pickerViewEarthquackzone
       }
       func dismissPickerView() {
        
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        //MARK: Assign TextBox to ToolBar
        occupancyTextBox.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        //        occupancycodeTextBox.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        //        earthquackzoneTextBox.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        }
     }
      //MARK: PickerView Methods
      extension ViewController {
     func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
     }
     // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
     func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 1
     }
    
    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        
        if occupancyTextBox.isEditing
        {
            return stateInfo.count
            //     return occupancy.count
        }
        //        else if occupancycodeTextBox.isEditing
        //        {
        //            return occupancycode.count
        //        }
        else
        {
            return occupancy.count
        }
      }
    
      internal func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        
        if occupancyTextBox.isEditing
        {
            return stateInfo[row].occupancycode
        }
                 `Code Works fine if we use Array`
        //        else if occupancycodeTextBox.isEditing
        //        {
        //            return occupancycode[row]
        //        }
        else
        {
            return occupancy[row]
            
        }
        
        }
    
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if occupancyTextBox.isEditing
        {
            
            selectedValue = stateInfo[row].occupancycode
            occupancyTextBox.text = "Occupancy: \(selectedValue)"
            occupancyValue = selectedValue
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
        //        else if occupancycodeTextBox.isEditing
        //        {
        //
        //            selectedValue = occupancycode[row]
        //            occupancycodeTextBox.text = "OccupancyCode: \(selectedValue)"
        //            occupancycodeValue = selectedValue
        //            self.view.endEditing(true)
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            selectedValue = earthquackzone[row]
        //            earthquackzoneTextBox.text = "EarthquackZone: \(selectedValue)"
        //            earthquackValue = selectedValue
        //            self.view.endEditing(true)
        //        }
              }
    
             }
```

Download the image to check the structure of Plist File and Data

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXbgX.png
```

Comment: You need to take things step-by-step... Are you successfully loading the data from the `.plist`? If not, start there. Next, are you able to create one picker view from that data? If not, do that. Then, are you able to create two picker views, and give each one different data? If not, do that. Finally, you can work on changing the data in the 2nd picker based on the selection from the 1st picker.

Comment: add your plist screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I am getting data from Plist. Yes I already created one picker or even two picker view, by allocating two different array to it. Currently I want to do is I want plist data in picker view, currently I am successfully getting plist data on console, not in picker view.

Comment: or How can I add plist data into array itself, if this is going to be done then also I will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `plist` is an Array of `[String : String]` dictionaries, you can load it like that instead of `[String : Any]` - so you already have your data array.

Using this `plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Occupancy Code</key>
        <string>1001</string>
        <key>Description of Occupancy</key>
        <string>Individual Dwelling</string>
        <key>FLEXA Rate</key>
        <string>0.14</string>
        <key>Colors</key>
        <string>Green</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Occupancy Code</key>
        <string>1002</string>
        <key>Description of Occupancy</key>
        <string>Multi Dwelling</string>
        <key>FLEXA Rate</key>
        <string>0.15</string>
        <key>Colors</key>
        <string>Blue</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Occupancy Code</key>
        <string>1003</string>
        <key>Description of Occupancy</key>
        <string>Individual House</string>
        <key>FLEXA Rate</key>
        <string>0.16</string>
        <key>Colors</key>
        <string>Red</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Which looks like this in the Xcode editor:

[image]

We can get a picker view with:

```
1001
1002
1003
```

using this code:

```
class LoadPlistVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    
    let pickerA = UIPickerView()
    
    var plistData: [[String : String]] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "firedata", withExtension: "plist") else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
        }
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [[String : String]]
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not load plist as [[String : Any]]")
        }
        
        // debugging
        //print(plistData)
        
        // successfully loaded the plist, so setup the UI
        
        pickerA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pickerA)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pickerA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pickerA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pickerA.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        pickerA.dataSource = self
        pickerA.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    // MARK: Picker View Methods
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return plistData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let d = plistData[row]
        return d["Occupancy Code"] ?? "No Code"
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("Picker selection - Row: \(row)")
    }
    
}
```